# Consume web API with client certificate authentication in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, webapi

I am consuming a web api which has client certificate authentication. I have both cert.pem, key.perm files. and I tested the api's in postman successfully by importing both files in certificate tab..
it works fine. but when i try to implement that api in my asp.net web application, it shows authentication failed error. i don't know how to use both cert.pem, key.perm files in authentication part of my coding.

I tried some codings.

```
 string url = "https://uat-api.ssg-wsg.sg/courses/runs/50331/sessions?uen=S89PB0005D&courseReferenceNumber=PA-S89PB0005D-01-Fuchun 354&sessionMonth=012021";

 ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
                       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

  X509Certificate clientCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/cert.pem"));

  HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format(url));
  WebReq.Method = "GET";

  WebReq.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
  HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();
  
  using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())   
  {
           StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
           jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
  }
```

Can anyone help me how to use both cert.pem, key.perm files in authentication part and make the api runs successfully..
Thank You.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is not use `WebRequest` in 2021 because it's obsolete. `HttpClient` is what you should be using and will likely work far better.

Comment: would be good to know if provided answer was correct or not

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that your cert.pem file is the certificate and the key.pem file contains the private key.
If you are using .net 5, you can do something like this:

```
var certificatePem = File.ReadAllText("cert.pem"); //you have to provide the correct path here
var key = File.RealAllText("key.pem"); //and here

var certificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(certificatePem, key);
```

Note the use of the new X509Certificate2 class.

if my initial asumption is not true, please post the text within the pem files (you can strip off a portion of the text, or you can gray out the relevant parts, of course)

Comment: @Haji this sample shows a correct solution. Maybe you should reward the bounty.